# Integrating pages into CMS shell

Tags: css

Here's the situation. It can't be changed, I have to deal with what I have.

I have a few pages of which I have styled inside a wrapper, two columns of various content.

I was given (after my pages were done) a shell which I now have to integrate the content. I wasn't to do this in the beginning; I was told to build and style as if these pages lived on their own.

So, now I have to essentially cut-n-paste my code into divs that are already styled as well as the structure to the overall page. All of my style declarations use entirely different names so that's good, but there are many styles that are causing problems.

I keep thinking there is a way to just add a class to the body and then over ride all other styles by the use of that class but I'm not sure about that. My tests haven't proved fruitful.

As there are three other style sheets that are called in the shell, I'm just trying to find the most painless and efficient way to integrate my content....like being able to insert everything into a iframe w/o using an iframe.

I have thought of duping all existing style sheets, renaming them and then just keeping the necessary styles from the cms but there will be a lot of extraneous css left over.

Any other ideas?

Comment: Iframed it. Works perfect, no css changes needed.

Comment: Using an iFrame is going to cause SEO problems. If SEO is a priority, you should probably just cut & paste your content divs into the new template.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you want to style the elements you are inserting without any clashes with the existing document stylesheets. Have you considered using a prefix so that for example '.container' would become '.my_container' e.t.c. This way to easily navigate the html and stylesheets for your elements you can just search for your prefix.